# How to save two table data in database using Active Record in yii2.0

Tags: forms, yii2

```
$model = new StickerOrder();
$model_shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();
```

Here in sticker_order table has foreign key -> shipping_address_id 
  I want first to save data in shipping_address table and then in sticker_order table.

Answer (score 1):

Save the shipping address first:

```
$model_shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();

// Assign attributes here

if (!$model_shipping_address->save()) {
    // Failed to save shipping address

    return ...
}
```

Then set the id of created shipping address to sticker order and save it as well:

```
$model_sticker_order = new StickerOrder();
$model_sticker_order->shipping_address_id = $model_shipping->id;

// Assign other attributes here  

if (!$model->save()) {
    // Failed to save sticker order

    return ...
}
```

Don't forget to check for successful savings in both models

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, so the others can know too.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this..

```
$model_shipping_address->attributes = $_POST[''];
$model_shipping_address->save();
if($model_shipping_address->save()) {
    $model->shipping_address_id = $model_shipping_address->id;
    $model->save()
return code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = new StickerOrder();
$model_shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();

if(($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) && ($model_shipping_address->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model_shipping_address->save()) ){
//do something
}
```